# Efficiently automate 4d Array reduction based on specific dimension value

Tags: arrays, automation, netcdf

As a preface, I am rather inexperienced so my terminology may be off, hence why I couldn't find anything when searching the forums.

I have a huge 4D array of atmospheric height data (hgt) for the year 1900 contained in a netcdf file. Conceptually, the scope of my project is simple, create a height climatology (mean height value at each grid point for each day of the year) at a couple specific pressure levels, involving 141 years of data (each yearly data file has identical format).

```
hgt_1900 = ncread('hgt.1900.nc','hgt')
n = numel(hgt_1900)
n = 143488800

size(hgt_1900)
ans = 180  91  24  365
```

The dimensions are longitude, latitude, pressure level, and time (days). Given the size of the array I thought limiting the data to one pressure level (ex: level 4) on one day was the way to go

```
hgt_1900_4_Day1 = hgt_1900(1:180, 1:91, 4, 1)
```

This returns a 180x91 single variable, which is great! However, by the time I got to hgt_1900_4_Day3 I figured there has to be a way to automate this process. So this is what I tried:

```
for day = 1:365
    hgt_1900_4_Day'day' = hgt_1900(1:180, 1:91, 4, 'day')
    day = +1
end
Error: File: Height850.m Line: 2 Column: 20
Unexpected MATLAB expression.
```

Can anybody shed light on ways to remedy this unexpected expression? I have tried (possibly incorrectly) using the genvarname function instead, which properly generated variable names, but keeps 4D variable format and does not get the correct day's data:

```
for day = 1:356
    t = hgt_1900(1:180, 1:91, 4, 'day');
    v = genvarname('hgt_1900_4_Day', who);
    eval([v ' = t'])
end

size(hgt_1900_4_Day1)
ans = 180  91  1  3

size(hgt_1900_4_Day350)
ans = 180  91  1  3
```

Assuming I can get the above to work, I was planning to run this script for each year of data. Then create the climatology by averaging hgt_1900_4_Day50, hgt_1901_4_Day50, etc ...

Given the cumulative size of the 141 years of data (20231920800 elements). I feel efficiency is critical, so please share any other, more efficient ways of arriving at the same place!

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Little confused. Do you want an annual-climatology (i.e. average over all days in a given year) for a specific pressure level?

Comment: Answered question below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My brother helped me get to the code below, which does what I need it to do!

```
for year = 1900:2012
    baseVar = genvarname(['hgt_' int2str(year) '_4_Day'])

    % Load hgt into memory

    for day = 1:365
        t = hgt(1:180, 1:91, 4, day);
        v = genvarname([baseVar int2str(day)]);
        eval([v ' = t;']);
    end
    clear hgt;
end
```

Thanks for your help!